# How merge records in a table and update the table as well?

Tags: sql, ms-access, merge, ms-access-2013

I have a table (named `Data_detailed`) that looks like this:

```
sample_year| Cell_ID | Species_ID | a     | b        | c     | d... 
2017       | 103.60  | PLALAG     | Adult |          | Adult |    
2017       | 103.60  | PLALAG     |       | Adult    | Adult |      
2017       | 103.60  | TRIMON     | Adult | Adult    | Adult | Seedling
2017       | 103.70  | ANTNST     |       | Adult    | Adult |  
2017       | 103.70  | AVESTE     |       | Adult    | Adult |  
2017       | 103.70  | AVESTE     | Adult | Seedling |       | Seedling
2017       | 103.70  | BROSCO     | Adult | Adult    |       |
```

It has three identifying fields, (`sample_year`,`Cell_ID` and `Species_ID`), and then some columns that can be either empty or contain one of two values: "Seedling" and "Adult".

As you can see, some combinations of my identifying fields repeat more than once (e.g. "AVESTE" in cell 103.7), and I want to combine them to a single record, using two simple rules:

1. For each field (`a`, `b` etc..), if there is a value - take it.
2. If you have both "Seedling" and "Adult" - select "Seedling".

So I have created a query to find all duplicated records with respect to my identifying fields (named `Data_detailed_duplicates`):

```
SELECT Data_detailed.sample_year, Data_detailed.Cell_ID, Data_detailed.Species_ID,
Count(Data_detailed.sample_year) AS CountOfsample_year
FROM Data_detailed
GROUP BY Data_detailed.sample_year, Data_detailed.Cell_ID, Data_detailed.Species_ID
HAVING (((Data_detailed.sample_year)=get_year())
    AND ((Data_detailed.Species_ID)<>"GENSPP"
    And (Data_detailed.Species_ID)<>"MEDSPP")
    AND ((Count(Data_detailed.sample_year))>1));
```

Then I created a query that merges this records by the rules above (I use `Max` for grouping because "Seedling" is coded as 0 and "Adult" as -1):

```
SELECT Data_detailed.sample_year, Data_detailed.Cell_ID, Data_detailed.Species_ID,
Max(Data_detailed.a) AS MaxOfa,
Max(Data_detailed.b) AS MaxOfb,
Max(Data_detailed.c) AS MaxOfc,
Max(Data_detailed.d) AS MaxOfd,
Max(Data_detailed.e) AS MaxOfe,
Max(Data_detailed.f) AS MaxOff,
Max(Data_detailed.g) AS MaxOfg,
Max(Data_detailed.h) AS MaxOfh,
Max(Data_detailed.InnerQ) AS MaxOfInnerQ
FROM Data_detailed INNER JOIN Data_detailed_duplicates
ON (Data_detailed.sample_year = Data_detailed_duplicates.sample_year)
    AND (Data_detailed.Species_ID = Data_detailed_duplicates.Species_ID)
    AND (Data_detailed.Cell_ID = Data_detailed_duplicates.Cell_ID)
GROUP BY Data_detailed.sample_year, Data_detailed.Cell_ID, Data_detailed.Species_ID
HAVING (((Data_detailed.Species_ID)<>"GENSPP" And (Data_detailed.Species_ID)<>"MEDSPP"));
```

So far everything works well.

But, instead of extracting all merged records in a query result, I want them to **actually update in the table**, so every two or more records that are merged will result in only one record, with all the information, and all other records will be deleted from the table. How do I do that?

The result for the example above would be:

```
sample_year| Cell_ID | Species_ID | a     | b        | c     | d... 
2017       | 103.60  | PLALAG     | Adult | Adult    | Adult |    
2017       | 103.60  | TRIMON     | Adult | Adult    | Adult | Seedling
2017       | 103.70  | ANTNST     |       | Adult    | Adult |  
2017       | 103.70  | AVESTE     | Adult | Seedling | Adult | Seedling
2017       | 103.70  | BROSCO     | Adult | Adult    |       |
```

Comment: Is this a one-time process to correct data or will this be an ongoing repeated process? Does not look like a normalized data structure.

Comment: @June7 this process should be done routinely, once a year, **on the same table**. I know I can create **new** table with the desired result, but I need to keep the same table updated, as it is connected to several other queries and forms. The data structure _is_ normalized, so I have another table for `Cell_ID` and for `Species_ID` and also for the possible states for all the columns that contain "Seedling" and "Adult". All tables are connected by relationships with referential integrity.

Comment: Structure still does not look fully normalized. Multiple similar fields is one indicator of that. Columns a, b, c, d look like same kind of data. Are there more alpha sequence field names after d?

Comment: @June7 columns `a` to `h` and also `InnerQ` (you can see their list in the second query) are of data from different spatial locations. I know I could use one column for location, and then put all of this data in the same column. That is how my main data table is structured, but this table is filled with a specific form that needs this structure for a parallel input of all locations per Cell and Species. How would you structure this table?

Comment: Seems like a related dependent table for LocationDetails would be needed for normalization. Regardless, why delete original raw data? Why alter data and not just do queries? Can't UPDATE and DELETE records in same sql, Every attempt I've ever made to update a table using an aggregate query failed. So suggest you save to a 'temp' table, delete records from the original table then run INSERT SELECT to repopulate the original table. This avoids having to delete and rename tables which are db design edits.

Comment: @June7 There are no "Location Details". These locations only have a symbol, no more than that. Also, as I wrote, I need this structure for an ease input by a form. Otherwise, I would have to view (and update) 9 records in parallel. As for your suggestion, I do this at another table, where I delete complete duplicates, but here I need to merge the records (i.e. copy some data between records) before deletion, and the LEFT JOIN (proposed below) is not a good solution.

Comment: My suggestion is to save the query into a 'temp' table (table is permanent, records are temporary), delete ALL records from the original table then repopulate it with the records from the 'temp' table.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**: I use a new field on the table to mark all duplicates, append them after merging to the table, and delete the marked records.

---

Here is how I solved the problem finally:

I use the first query (`Data_detailed_duplicates`) for creating a list of all records to be merged, and the second query (`Data_detailed_merged_duplicates`) to create a list of records that should substitute the duplicates in the table. All of this just as mentioned in the question.

Next, I create a new field (`Duplicates`) in my table, and use the following update query to mark all the duplicated records:

```
UPDATE DISTINCTROW Data_detailed_duplicates
INNER JOIN Data_detailed ON (Data_detailed_duplicates.sample_year = Data_detailed.sample_year)
    AND (Data_detailed_duplicates.Cell_ID = Data_detailed.Cell_ID)
    AND (Data_detailed_duplicates.Species_ID = Data_detailed.Species_ID)
SET Data_detailed.Duplicates = 1
WHERE (((Data_detailed.Duplicates)=False));
```

Now I use another query to append all the merged records to the table:

```
INSERT INTO Data_detailed ( sample_year, Cell_ID, Species_ID, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, InnerQ, Duplicates )
SELECT Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.sample_year,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.Cell_ID,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.Species_ID,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfa,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfb,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfc,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfd,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfe,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOff,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfg,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfh,
    Data_detailed_merged_duplicates.MaxOfInnerQ,
    0 AS Expr1
FROM Data_detailed_merged_duplicates;
```

And finally, I delete all the duplicated records (now they are at least triplets,  but only one unmarked) that I marked before with another query:

```
DELETE Data_detailed.*, Data_detailed.Duplicates
FROM Data_detailed
WHERE (((Data_detailed.Duplicates)=True));
```

SO I get all the records to be merged, without creating a temporary table.

All this process is encapsulated into a macro, so I won't have to look for all these queries and apply them one by one:

[image: macro]